# How to read multiple Lidars using ROS 2 with sick_scan2 library

Tags: lidar, ros2

I use ROS2 and library sick_scan2 (https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_scan2.git), what would you recommend for reading multiple scanners and publishing them on different topics?

**EDIT:**

Solution: create an extra launch file and config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> recommend for reading multiple scanners

Do you mean subscribing? I suppose that since in ROS terminology, you read a message by creating a subscriber to the relevant topic. Then what you can do is to create separate subscribers and callbacks for each of the two topics. In these callbacks, you can process the scan data and publish other relevant message(s).

The link you provided is a driver package for your scanner. If your only aim is to make scanning data available in ROS topics, you do not need to subscribe and publish again. The driver will already make the scanned data available in a topic. Though if you want to use the scan data, you can follow the above procedure

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, if I use sick_scann2 driver. I just need to create an extra launch file and config file in order to publish data from two scanners.